# duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/AnyRes.class

Tags: android, duplicates, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I am not sure what this error means.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/AnyRes.class
```

and here is my library dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
     compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.ms-square:etsyblur:0.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview:library:0.3.4'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
}
```

any help would be appreciate.

Comment: do you have added any **jars** to your libs folder or if so can you list them too ?

Comment: i have httpclient-4.3.6.jar  httpcore-4.3.3.jar httpmime-4.3.6.jar in libs folder

Answer (score 0):

Any `duplicate entry` error in `Android` happen because you have 2 or more times the same `library` available, standalone or included in another lib

Comment: So what.  Gradle should handle `exclude` statements gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Please try remove the support v4 from your gradle file as you are using v7

Answer (score 0):

If you run **./gradlew -q app:dependencies**, you will that the **play-services** libraries have a ton of transitive dependencies.  To mitigate that, put the following in your build.gradle:

`compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0') {
    exclude  group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}`